# I can't run indivual test files in my Dart plugin

Tags: android, unit-testing, dart, flutter

I'm developing a plugin for Dart and Flutter and I've started with a suite of tests, since it's porting from a java implementation.

The issue I'm seeing is that I can run all tests, but I can't run a single test file, or debug it.

I used the Android studio project generator and chose "Flutter Package"

I belive the issue lies with android studio not recognizing the tests as flutter tests and failing to include the required imports.

The test code looks like the following;

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  test('Test Name', () {
    ///Test cases in here
  });
}
```

And the error I'm seeing when trying to run or debug indivual tests are;

```
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/accessibility.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/matchers.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/matchers.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/test_pointer.dart:12:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
export 'dart:ui' show Offset;
^
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/binding.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show window;
       ^
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug_overflow_indicator.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/editable.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show TextBox, lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/error.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paragraph, ParagraphBuilder, ParagraphConstraints, ParagraphStyle, TextStyle;
       ^

Process finished with exit code 254
```

Is there some other configuration step I'm missing here, or an alternate to `package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart` I should be using here?

I attempted to swap out the flutter tests with the pure dart ones, but then no tests would even load. The error was;

`Failed to load test harness. Are you missing a dependency on flutter_test?`

Comment: Try opening the console in your project dir and type`flutter test filename.dart` or `flutter test test/filename.dart`

Comment: try to get dependency in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK so I actually found a solution for this.

In Android studio in the run dropdown you select **Edit Configurations**
Then you press the **+** button and select **Flutter test**
Make sure the Test scope is **All in file** and point it at your test file.
You can now run the individual test file and also debug it in android studio by selecting this configuration in the run drop-down.

Comment: I'd like to add here, I selected "Dart Test" thinking it'd have the same outcome - I ran into the following `Could not find package \`test\` or file \`test\``. Make sure to select **Flutter Test** *(test ran `C:\Users\cybex\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe run test -r json C:/Users/cybex/FlutterProjects/test_app/test/widget_test.dart`)*

Comment: How to right click and run tests only for a single file?