# create folder under test folder Flutter

Tags: unit-testing, testing, flutter

I'm new in Flutter, i started creating unit tests and UI interface tests, if i put the tests classes under test directory everything works fine, but when i decided to separate UI and unitTest in separate folders under test folder

> **test**/unitTest/test1.dart
>
> **test**/ui/widget1.dart

I got an error

> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'

is it possible to create folders under test folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution

> OK so I actually found a solution for this.
>
> In Android studio in the run dropdown you select Edit Configurations
>   Then you press the + button and select Flutter test Make sure the Test
>   scope is All in file and point it at your test file. You can now run
>   the individual test file and also debug it in android studio by
>   selecting >this configuration in the run drop-down.

chose **Flutter test** > click **+** > **Flutter test** > click **Test File** > select the test file from your project.

Origin solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527599/i-cant-run-indivual-test-files-in-my-dart-plugin/56589941#56589941)

[image: 1][image]

Comment: We should be able to right click -> Run to run the unit tests. This approach is not scalable as we need to apply this to all files.